# How are pre-sale Augur's REPs stored on the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: contract-design, augur

Does Augur's REP exist as Ethereum coin contract?

If so, does the coin contract already deployed on the Ethereum blockchain? What is the contract address for it?
If not, how do you know how many REP is owned by crowd-sale buyers?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "keep rep" by storing it in any ethereum wallet you have access to the private keys of.

Private keys can own/control contract data on ethereum

Rep will exist as a token contract; not deployed yet

Comment: Sorry for the bad question. Does REP exist as coin contract? If so, it the coin contract already deployed on the Ethereum blockchain?

Comment: @SatoshiNakanishi comments are not intended to ask additional questions. You can improve your initial question by editing it. If you have additional questions, please use [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). This would allow others to better find your question and contribute to answering it.

Comment: I changed the question.